# Is here an editor for linux terminal like there is for MS-DOS?

Tags: terminal, editors

I know that there is an editor built into MS-DOS, so you can create batch (.bat) files. But is there something like that for Linux Mint 12 terminal?

Comment: FYI, there is no editor *built-in* to MS-DOS, but most installations include EDIT.COM to do basic editing.

Answer (score 11):

**For editing/creating files from shell:**

Most linux distros come with [`nano`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/nano-basics-guide.xml) which is quite friendly.

Another alternative would be [`vi`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial), but that's a little more complicated.

**For a '.bat' equivalent for sequencing commands:**

Depending on the shell you are using (most likely `bash`) you will need to write shell script, traditionally with a `.sh` extension (or with no extension, using a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)). The syntax depends on the shell that is interpreting the script. If you are using bash, then you should investigate [bash scripting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html). Examples of other shells include `zsh`, `csh`, `pash`, and Ipython shell; but `bash` is the most common by far.

Note that shell scripts require execution permissions to run. You would set these using `chmod` (e.g. `chmod u+x <filename>`)

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu, which ships with `nano` by default, so I think it's already installed.

Comment: so I can put in commands to be executed later? and if so what file extension should i give them?

Comment: @IkechiAnyanwu Ah you are actually asking a slightly different question. I will update in a minute.

Comment: ed is the standard editor

Comment: @AndyRoss yes, however I didnt mention it since while it is arguably the most available, it is also not as newbie friendly as `nano` is. And if one goes down the modal editor route, then they might as well go for a `vi` variant...

Comment: It was a joke.  For years and years, long after it was obsolete, the man page for "ed" began with "ed is the standard editor".  See: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EdIsTheStandardTextEditor

Comment: @AndyRoss hah, my bad :).

Comment: You can try either Vim or Emacs. I prefer Emacs because its a little more intuitive than Vim, but I use both and they are both great. Also read [Learning the Vi and Vim Editors](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Vim-Editors-Arnold-Robbins/dp/059652983X) and [GNU Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html)